# jQuery cycly plugin isn't working online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I'm trying this code, everything working perfectly. 
But after I've upload it to github pages it's horribly.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CoffeeTech Slider</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <h1>CoffeeTech</h1>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="img/slide1.jpg" width="640" height="426">
            <img src="img/slide2.jpg" width="640" height="426">
            <img src="img/slide3.jpg" width="640" height="426">
            <img src="img/slide4.jpg" width="640" height="426">
            <img src="img/slide5.jpg" width="640" height="426">
        </div>

        <ul id="nav">
            <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
            <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').cycle({
            fx: 'turnDown',
            pause: 1,
            prev: '#prev',
            next: '#next'
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Github link](https://github.com/rubik951/FullStack-Course/tree/master/jQuery%20Image%20Slider) 
[The page it's displaying horribly](https://rubik951.github.io/FullStack-Course/jQuery%20Image%20Slider/index.html)

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Try `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: Thanks, I added 's' and it fixed everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xufox is right, I have a message in the console in Firefox:
Mixed content blocked on loading
 http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js

It seems linked to the fact that your page works with https and you load content form http link
[More about mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/S%C3%A9curit%C3%A9/MixedContent)